# Using Puppet apt module

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, apt

I'm an absolute beginner at Puppet, and I'm having an issue when I try to install a package via the apt-module.

```
class newrelic {
        apt::source {
                'newrelic':location => 'http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/',
                repos => 'non-free',
                key => '548C16BF',
                key_source => 'https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg',
                include_src => false,
                release => 'newrelic',
        }
        package {
                'newrelic-sysmond':ensure => 'present',
                notify => Service['newrelic-sysmond'],
                require => Class['apt::source'],
        }
        service {
                'newrelic-sysmond':ensure => 'running',
                enable => true,
                hasrestart => true,
                hasstatus => true,
                require => Exec['newrelic_config'],
        }
        exec {
                'newrelic_config':path => '/bin:/usr/bin',
                command => "/usr/sbin/nrsysmond-config --set license_key=xxxxxxx",
                user => 'root',
                group => 'root',
                require => Package['newrelic-sysmond'],
                notify => Service['newrelic-sysmond'],
        }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Warning: Scope(Class[Apt::Update]): Could not look up qualified variable '::apt::always_apt_update'; class ::apt has not been evaluated
Warning: Scope(Class[Apt::Update]): Could not look up qualified variable 'apt::update_timeout'; class apt has not been evaluated
Warning: Scope(Class[Apt::Update]): Could not look up qualified variable 'apt::update_tries'; class apt has not been evaluated
Notice: Compiled catalog for host.domain.local in environment production in 0.33 seconds
Error: Could not find dependency Class[Apt::Source] for Package[newrelic-sysmond] at /home/jeroen/puppet/modules/newrelic/manifests/init.pp:16
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in my module?

Comment: Eyeballing it, once this is fixed I'm not sure if you'll get dependency cycle problems or not. You might do, OTTOMH I'm not certain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `include apt` at the top of your class, before the `apt::source` declaration: the error is saying it can't find `apt::things` because it doesn't know what the higher scope `apt` is.

The `include apt` will use various defaults, if you want to change them you'll need to instead use a declaration such as:

```
class { 'apt':
    always_apt_update => true,
}
```

...for example. More info on the [forge page](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt).

Also, your require is wrong: you need to specify the name as well, so I think it should be `Apt::Source['newrelic']` instead of `Class['apt::source']`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't resolve the dependency issue. How do I instruct Puppet that the package depends on the configuration of the repository?

Comment: Maybe you should post that last reply as an answer, so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JeroenJacobs - done, I've updated this one and deleted the comment!